# Need to add common UIBarButtonItem across all VCs

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Following is piece of code which is not working:

```
class Person {

        static fun addBtn(cName:UIViewController)
        {
           let rightBtn = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Right", style: .Plain, target: UIBarButtonItem.self, action:#selector(UIBarButtonItem.self.newMenuTapped(_:)))
           cName.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = rightBtn
        }

    }
    extension UIBarButtonItem
    {

        func newMenuTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
        {
        print("Tapped")
        }

    }
```

Crashes with this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: unrecognized selector sent to
>   class 0x14c830

Can someone guide be as to what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an extension for `UIViewController` like this:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func addButton() {
        let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.rightButtonPressed(_:)))
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(button, animated: false)
    }

    func rightButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("tapped")
    }
}
```

And call `self.addButton()` in all view controllers where you want to implement the button.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be create a `BaseViewController`, subclass of `UIViewController`.

Create a simple method to add a navigation bar and navigation bar item.
Make this `BaseViewcontroller` a superclass of all views where you want similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. @xoudini

Following was what was wrong with my code:-

```
    class Person 
    {

      static func addBtn(cName: UIViewController)
        {

    let rightBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "RightView", style: .Plain, target: UIBarButtonItem(), action: #selector(UIBarButtonItem.newMenuTapped(_:)))
            cName.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn
        }
    }

extension UIBarButtonItem {
        func newMenuTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
        {
            print("Tapped 3")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension of UIViewController and put this code snippet inside that.

```
extension UIViewController 
{
   func addRightBarButtonItem()
   {
      var btn = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "Right",
            style: .Plain,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(newMenuTapped(_:))
        )
      self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(btn, animated: false)
   }
    func newMenuTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: use this function in your BaseViewController and will work for all viewcontroller

Comment: @Meet Shah yes do this as Dev said.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!